# Не срабатывает функция javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени! Собствено есть такой код:

```js
window.onload=function(){

  $(".hidafi").click(function (el) { 

    $(el).children("ul").css('display','block');

  });

$(".hidafi").children("ul").children("li").click(function () { 
 

$(this).parent("ul").css('display','none');

});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="hidafi">
    <ul style='display: none;'><li></li></ul>
  </li>
  <li class="hidafi">
    <ul style='display: none;'><li></li></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

По задумке он работает так: при клике на элемент с классом hidafi у его потомка ul свойство дисплей должно становиться в позицию block но почему то это не так, подскажите где ошибка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первый параметр в коллбэке [функции click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) - это не элемент, по которому кликнули, а объект событие.

Для решения стоит использовать вместо него `this`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $(".hidafi").click(function() {
    $(this).children("ul").css('display', 'block');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="hidafi">1
    <ul style='display: none;'>
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="hidafi">2
    <ul style='display: none;'>
      <li>2.1</li>
      <li>2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Ответ на дополненный вопрос: из-за системы всплытия событий, в твоем случае после обработчика клика на внутренний `li` событие всплывает и выполняется обработчик внешнего `li`.

Чтобы этого избежать, можно воспользоваться объектом события, которое передается первым параметром, вызвав у него метод [stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/), либо вернуть `false` из функции обработчика

Примеры

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $(".hidafi").click(function() {
    $(this).children("ul").css('display', 'block');
  });
  $(".hidafi").children("ul").children("li").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent("ul").css('display', 'none');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="hidafi">1
    <ul style='display: none;'>
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="hidafi">2
    <ul style='display: none;'>
      <li>2.1</li>
      <li>2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $(".hidafi").click(function() {
    $(this).children("ul").css('display', 'block');
  });
  $(".hidafi").children("ul").children("li").click(function() {
    $(this).parent("ul").css('display', 'none');
    return false;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="hidafi">1
    <ul style='display: none;'>
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="hidafi">2
    <ul style='display: none;'>
      <li>2.1</li>
      <li>2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно! А не подскажите еще вот для обратного дейсвтия при клике на потомка скрывать этот список вот таким js как? $(".hidafi").children("ul").children("li").click(function () { 
  
 
 $(this).parent("ul").css('display','none');

 });   @Grundy

Comment: @dantelol, а твой код не работает? :-)

Comment: @Gundy такой нет почему то\

Comment: @dantelol, добавь этот пример в сниппет в вопросе, чтобы было видно где и как вызываешь

Comment: гтово) там же и вызываю)

Comment: @dantelol, обновил ответ